# Echo Total Sales From Specific Stores

Tags: magento-1.9, sales

I'm currently building a Magento Platform where I need to echo out the total sales from individual stores on a page (Like it does on the Dashboard home screen):

[image: Total sales per store]

I've found some code in:

/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Totals.php

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Totals extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Dashboard_Bar
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('dashboard/totalbar.phtml');
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        if (!Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Reports')) {
            return $this;
        }
        $isFilter = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('website') || $this->getRequest()->getParam('group');
        $period = $this->getRequest()->getParam('period', '24h');

        /* @var $collection Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection')
            ->addCreateAtPeriodFilter($period)
            ->calculateTotals($isFilter);

        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('store')) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', $this->getRequest()->getParam('store'));
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('website')){
            $storeIds = Mage::app()->getWebsite($this->getRequest()->getParam('website'))->getStoreIds();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));
        } else if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('group')){
            $storeIds = Mage::app()->getGroup($this->getRequest()->getParam('group'))->getStoreIds();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('in' => $storeIds));
        } elseif (!$collection->isLive()) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id',
                array('eq' => Mage::app()->getStore(Mage_Core_Model_Store::ADMIN_CODE)->getId())
            );
        }

        $collection->load();

        $totals = $collection->getFirstItem();

        $this->addTotal($this->__('Revenue'), $totals->getRevenue());
        $this->addTotal($this->__('Tax'), $totals->getTax());
        $this->addTotal($this->__('Shipping'), $totals->getShipping());
        $this->addTotal($this->__('Quantity'), $totals->getQuantity()*1, true);
    }
}
```

To where I think it 'gets' the value but I'm not sure on how I could echo this out somewhere else?

I've also looked over the net to try and find functions close to this, obviously I found a few on how to get the store ID, but nothing on how to get that stores total sales.

Any ideas appreciated greatly.

Comment: No one has any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is there... but you have to modify it a little bit to get what you want.
Here is your datasource:

```
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection')
        ->calculateTotals(true);
```

here is the storefilter:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('store_id', {YOUR_STORE_ID});
```

and here are your values from query:

```
$collection->load();

    $totals = $collection->getFirstItem();

    $this->addTotal($this->__('Revenue'), $totals->getRevenue());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Tax'), $totals->getTax());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Shipping'), $totals->getShipping());
    $this->addTotal($this->__('Quantity'), $totals->getQuantity()*1, true);
```

all together it would be:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection')
        ->calculateTotals(true)
        ->addFieldToFilter('store_id', {YOUR_STORE_ID})->load();
$totals = $collection->getFirstItem();
echo $totals->getRevenue();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've managed to echo the relevant totals. Thanks.